# Install SSH Server onto a VM running Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I am trying to set up and enable SSH onto a VM that is running Ubuntu

I am following the instructions from here https://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-enable-ssh-ubuntu/

However I am stuck on the first step **Setting up SSH**.  I want to install a SSH Server so I open up a terminal and type
`sudo apt-get install openssh-server`

The program responds with a message saying that the openssh-server have unmet dependencies.
[sudo apt-get install openssh-server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LojPl.png)

If you can provide me with ANY information that will help me solve this problem, I will be forever grateful

Answer (score 0):

looks like it depends on openssh client and sftp server

try installing it manually

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client=1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1
sudo apt-get install openssh-sftp-server
```

or

```
sudo aptitude install openssh-client=1:6.6p1-2ubuntu1
sudo aptitude install openssh-sftp-server
```

Answer (score 0):

`openssh-server` is really a common packages, so it's very unlikely to be really broken.

Perhaps some dependencies are not available anymore, but are available with updated versions.

So `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade the system, it is likely to have an old system with old packages, or maybe there is problem with your system installation.

To try upgrading your system, call:

```
sudo apt update && apt upgrade -y
```

If not, then try this:

```
sudo apt update && apt dist-upgrade -y
```

Then try to reinstall

```
sudo apt install -y openssh-server
```